# AspNetCore 2.0 + signalR 1.0.0 alpha2 add pipeline or middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, signalr-2

In an older version of SignalR and .NetFreamwork i used the class inherit the class HubPipelineModule like :

```
public class IsConnectedPipeLine : HubPipelineModule
{
    protected override bool OnBeforeIncoming(IHubIncomingInvokerContext context)
    {
        if (context.MethodDescriptor.Name == "GetToken")
            return true;
        return ChatIdentity.CheckToken(context.Hub.Context.GetCurrentUserToken());
    }
}
```

Now i want to start developing in .NetCore 2.0 and SignalR 1.0.0 alpha 2
but I do not know how to implement pipe line, middleware or something like costum ActionAttribute in Web API controller, i do not care how, basically i need the OnBeforeIncoming functionality.

I searched and found only [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubpipeline) but it is very old and not for new versions.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/924

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing what is listed here and where this chain of posts leads.

[Here is the proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5353#issuecomment-611239847) that was eventually created and used for net core signalr for similar effect to the HubPipelineModule

[and here is a link to documentation on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hub-filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

and if you're curious... [Here's documentation on filters in general](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

If you're like me, you'll find this section particularly helpful for writing your own filters

[Exception catching filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-filters-1)

In my own experience I had a lil scare figuring out how to use it, since I was on net core 3.1 instead of 5.0. 5.0 has the `AddFilter` call available.